# Data gets distorted which is printed in loop

Tags: c, linux, malloc

Facing issue when printing the data that is updated in malloc. In the below code am creating a string Test.DataType_1.Tag_1 .... Test.DataType_1.Tag_20 in create_tags() function, when the data is updated properly and printed i create_tags() function it prints properly but if printed in main() function in for loop data is distorted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define NUM_OF_TAGS            (20)
#define NUM_DATA_TYPES         (01)

#define MAX_SUBSCRIPTION        (1)
#define MAX_MONITORED_ITEMS     (2)
#define MAX_ITEMS_TO_CREATE     (20)
   
typedef struct
{
    char nodeID[50];
}TAG_NAME;

typedef struct
{
    int32_t group_id;
    TAG_NAME *tag;
}GROUP;


int32_t max_subscription;
int32_t max_monitored_item;
int32_t max_item_to_create;

void create_tags(GROUP *node)
{
    char t_node[50];
    char r_node[50];
    memset(r_node, 0, sizeof(r_node));
    memset(t_node, 0, sizeof(t_node));

    for(int i = 1; i <= NUM_OF_TAGS; i++)
    {
        sprintf(t_node, "Test.DataType_1.Tag_%d", i);
        strcat(r_node, t_node);
        strcpy(node->tag[i].nodeID, r_node);
        printf("%s\n", node->tag[i].nodeID);
        memset(t_node, 0, sizeof(t_node));
        memset(r_node, 0, sizeof(r_node));
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    max_subscription = MAX_SUBSCRIPTION;
    max_monitored_item = MAX_MONITORED_ITEMS;
    max_item_to_create = MAX_ITEMS_TO_CREATE;

    GROUP *group = NULL;
    /* Grouping Nodes */
    group = malloc(sizeof(GROUP) * max_subscription * max_monitored_item);
    for(int j = 0; j < max_subscription * max_monitored_item; j++)
    {
        group[j].tag  = malloc(sizeof(GROUP) * max_item_to_create);
        memset(group[j].tag, 0, sizeof(GROUP) * max_item_to_create);
        printf("########## Set %d: Start ###########\n", j);
        group[j].group_id = j;
        create_tags(&group[j]);
        printf("########## End %d: Start ###########\n", j);
        printf("\n");
    }

    int32_t count = 0;


    for(int32_t i = 0; i < max_subscription; i++)
    {
        for(int32_t j = 0; j < max_monitored_item; j++)
        {
            printf("============= Start: %d ===============\n", count );
            for (int32_t k = 0; k < max_item_to_create; k++)
            {
                printf("%s\n", group[count].tag[k].nodeID);
            }
            printf("============= End: %d ===============\n", count);
            count++;
        }
    }

}
```

The output of the code is follows, when i print the data inside create_tags() function, the data populated is correctly printed here am printing the same data twice.
But when i print the same in loops it get distorted in `printf("%s\n", group[count].tag[k].nodeID);`

```
########## Set 0: Start ###########
Test.DataType_1.Tag_1
Test.DataType_1.Tag_2
Test.DataType_1.Tag_3
Test.DataType_1.Tag_4
Test.DataType_1.Tag_5
Test.DataType_1.Tag_6
Test.DataType_1.Tag_7
Test.DataType_1.Tag_8
Test.DataType_1.Tag_9
Test.DataType_1.Tag_10
Test.DataType_1.Tag_11
Test.DataType_1.Tag_12
Test.DataType_1.Tag_13
Test.DataType_1.Tag_14
Test.DataType_1.Tag_15
Test.DataType_1.Tag_16
Test.DataType_1.Tag_17
Test.DataType_1.Tag_18
Test.DataType_1.Tag_19
Test.DataType_1.Tag_20
########## End 0: Start ###########

########## Set 1: Start ###########
Test.DataType_1.Tag_1
Test.DataType_1.Tag_2
Test.DataType_1.Tag_3
Test.DataType_1.Tag_4
Test.DataType_1.Tag_5
Test.DataType_1.Tag_6
Test.DataType_1.Tag_7
Test.DataType_1.Tag_8
Test.DataType_1.Tag_9
Test.DataType_1.Tag_10
Test.DataType_1.Tag_11
Test.DataType_1.Tag_12
Test.DataType_1.Tag_13
Test.DataType_1.Tag_14
Test.DataType_1.Tag_15
Test.DataType_1.Tag_16
Test.DataType_1.Tag_17
Test.DataType_1.Tag_18
Test.DataType_1.Tag_19
Test.DataType_1.Tag_20
########## End 1: Start ###########

============= Start: 0 ===============

Test.DataType_1.Tag_1
Test.DataType_1.Tag_2
Test.DataType_1.Tag_3
Test.DataType_1.Tag_4
Test.DataType_1.Tag_5
Test.DataType_1.Tag_6
1.Tag_6
 ===============

Test.DataType_1.Tag_8
Test.DataType_1.Tag_9
Test.DataType_1.Tag_10
Test.DataType_1.Tag_11
Test.DataType_1.Tag_12
Test.DataType_1.Tag_13
Test.DataType_1.Tag_14
Test.DataType_1.Tag_15
Test.DataType_1.Tag_16
Test.DataType_1.Tag_17
Test.DataType_1.Tag_18
Test.DataType_1.Tag_19
============= End: 0 ===============

============= Start: 1 ===============

Test.DataType_1.Tag_1
Test.DataType_1.Tag_2
Test.DataType_1.Tag_3
Test.DataType_1.Tag_4
Test.DataType_1.Tag_5
Test.DataType_1.Tag_6
Test.DataType_1.Tag_7
Test.DataType_1.Tag_8
Test.DataType_1.Tag_9
Test.DataType_1.Tag_10
Test.DataType_1.Tag_11
Test.DataType_1.Tag_12
Test.DataType_1.Tag_13
Test.DataType_1.Tag_14
Test.DataType_1.Tag_15
Test.DataType_1.Tag_16
Test.DataType_1.Tag_17
Test.DataType_1.Tag_18
Test.DataType_1.Tag_19
============= End: 1 ===============
```

Any hint as to why this is happening will be helpful.

Comment: `group[j].tag  = malloc(sizeof(GROUP) * max_item_to_create);` -> `group[j].tag  = malloc(sizeof(TAG_NAME) * max_item_to_create);`. Same for the `memset` after that.

Comment: thank you, very silly mistake by my side.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_TAGS; i++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `main` function, you allocate both the `group` array, and the `tag` array within it, with an element size of `sizeof(GROUP)`. In addition, you use that same size when zeroing out the tag array:

```
group = malloc(sizeof(GROUP) * max_subscription * max_monitored_item);

group[j].tag  = malloc(sizeof(GROUP) * max_item_to_create);
memset(group[j].tag, 0, sizeof(GROUP) * max_item_to_create);
```

Since `GROUP` consists of an integer and pointer, it's almost certainly going to be smaller that the 50-byte `TAG_NAME`. That would mean you don't allocate enough space for it, probably leading to buffer overruns in the memory arena later on, where your code assumes it has enough space.

You should use `sizeof(TAG_NAME)` when allocating (and zeroing) the `tag` array. But, given you *want* to zero-initialise it, you may want to use `calloc` instead of the `malloc/memset` combo:

```
group[j].tag  = calloc(max_item_to_create, sizeof(TAG_NAME));
```